# how to send application/x-www-form-urlencoded JSON string in python botlle server

Tags: python, bottle

I want to post a JSON string in the format of

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

using python's bottle

Here's the web service I had written

```
import json
from bottle import route, run, request

@route('/ocr_response2', method='POST')
def ocr_response2():
    word = request.json
    print word


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I know this would work if `contentType: "application/json",`
But can't figure out if content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Here's how i am sending the data

```
import requests

d = {'spam': 20, 'eggs': 3}
requests.post("http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8080", data=d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `request.forms.get('spam')`

also in `requests.post` url should be `http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:8080/ocr_response2`